# Val for two separate selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can successfully val() the first of two  forms and change CSS depending on the option selected by the user.

But I cannot do the same thing for another  form right below it. It seems to only work on the first.

This is what I've got so far:

jQuery:

```
// Race images

    $('select[name=raceselect]').val();

  if (!selectedValue) {
      $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "0px 0px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Orc")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-32px -128px");
 }
else if (selectedValue === "Troll")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-32px 0px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Undead")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-64px 0px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Tauren")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-96px 0px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Human")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "0px -32px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Night Elf")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-64px -32px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Gnome")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-96px -32px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Dwarf")  {
  $('.comp_race').css("background-position", "-32px -32px");
 }



 $(function() {
    $("#classselect").change(function() {

// Class images

    $('select[name=classselect]').val();

  if (!selectedValue) {
      $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "0px 0px");
 }
else if (selectedValue === "Warrior")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "0px -96px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Hunter")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-64px -64px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Rogue")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-96px -96px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Paladin")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-32px -64px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Shaman")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "0px -64px");
 }
else if (selectedValue === "Warlock")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-32px -96px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Priest")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "0px -128px");
 }
 else if (selectedValue === "Mage")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-96px -64px");
 }
  else if (selectedValue === "Druid")  {
  $('.comp_class').css("background-position", "-64px -96px");
 }


 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comp_race">
        <select name="raceselect" id="raceselect">
            <option value="" selected>Choose a race</option>
            <option value="Orc">Orc</option>
            <option value="Troll">Troll</option>
            <option value="Undead">Undead</option>
            <option value="Tauren">Tauren</option>
            <option value="Human">Human</option>
            <option value="Night Elf">Night Elf</option>
            <option value="Gnome">Gnome</option>
            <option value="Dwarf">Dwarf</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="comp_class">
        <select name="classselect" id="classselect">
            <option value="" selected>Choose a class</option>
            <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>
            <option value="Hunter">Hunter</option>
            <option value="Rogue">Rogue</option>
            <option value="Paladin">Paladin</option>
            <option value="Shaman">Shaman</option>
            <option value="Warlock">Warlock</option>
            <option value="Priest">Priest</option>
            <option value="Mage">Mage</option>
            <option value="Druid">Druid</option>

        </select>
        </div>
```

When I use the first dropdown select the CSS changes like I want it to (it's changing the background position of a large image sprite). But using the same code after for the second  element doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using $("#raceselect").val(); method of val instead of the 'select[name=raceselect]' one... but this hasn't made a difference.

Is there something I'm missing like not 'ending' the first val() call properly, so that the script can then see the next val()?

If that is all a bit confusing: the end product I'd love to see would be this:

- Two  dropdowns
- When user chooses options on each dropdown, CSS changes for the element being used (at the moment it's just one of the  elements, the other one won't work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your javascript seems to be missing something. Where it says :

```
 $('select[name=raceselect]').val();
```

I think you meant to put

```
var selectedValue = $('select[name=raceselect]').val();
```

Comment: Hey Myke, I just tried that for both val entries and it’s still the same unfortunately. Any other ideas? EDIT working now! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your select option value to a variable. Also you have to target the selected option value.

```
var selectedValue = $('select[name=raceselect] option:selected').val();
```

These are a few other changes I would make. The main on is to use the switch statement instead of the if and if else. The switch is more efficient and can be faster than the many if else statements.

```
$('select[name="classselect"]').on('change', function () {
    var selectvalue = $(this, ' option:selected').val(),
          bgPosition = '';

    switch(selectvalue){
        case 'Warrior':
            bgPosition = '0px -96px';
            break;
        case 'Hunter':
            bgPosition = '-64px -64px';
            break;
        case 'Rogue':
            bgPosition = '-96px -96px';
            break;
        case 'Paladin':
            bgPosition = '-32px -64px';
            break;
        case 'Shaman':
            bgPosition = '0px -64px';
            break;
        case 'Warlock':
            bgPosition = '0px -64px';
            break;
        case 'Priest':
            bgPosition = '-32px -96px';
            break;
        case 'Mage':
            bgPosition = '0px -128px';
            break;
        case 'Mage':
            bgPosition = '-96px -64px';
            break;
        case 'Druid':
            bgPosition = '-64px -96px';
            break;
        default :
            bgPosition = '0px 0px';
            break;
    }

    $('.comp_class').css("background-position", bgPosition);
});



$('select[name=raceselect]').on('change', function () {
    var selectvalue = $(this, ' option:selected').val(),
          bgPosition = '';

    switch(selectvalue){
        case 'Orc':
            bgPosition = '-32px -128px';
            break;
        case 'Troll':
            bgPosition = '-32px 0px';
            break;
        case 'Undead':
            bgPosition = '-64px 0px';
            break;
        case 'Tauren':
            bgPosition = '-96px 0px';
            break;
        case 'Human':
            bgPosition = '0px -32px';
            break;
        case 'Night Elf':
            bgPosition = '-64px -32px';
            break;
        case 'Gnome':
            bgPosition = '-96px -32px';
            break;
        case 'Dwarf':
            bgPosition = '-96px -32px';
            break;
        default :
            bgPosition = '0px 0px';
            break;
    }

    $('.comp_race').css("background-position", bgPosition);
});
```